# Emacs completion list, one option is prefix of another selection

Tags: emacs, completion

Is there a way to indicate end of line for completion?

In below example, I just want to select "Python", but Enter doesn't allow me.

Psudocode, some thing like "Python$" do indicate completion is complete. Don't consider suffixes

---

```
In this buffer, type RET to select the completion near point.                                            

Possible completions are:                                                                                
*Python Doc*                                                                                             
*Python*                                                                                                 
-UUU:%*--F1  *Completions*   All (1,0)      [(Completion List [3]  Projectile[caffe] my-keys Anzu back)] 
Jump to buffer: Python
```

Comment: The question is not clear. Show the code that provides completion, or give a step-by-step recipe to reproduce, starting from `emacs -Q` (no init file). This works fine, for example: `(completing-read "foo: " '("*Python Doc*" "*Python*") nil t)`

Comment: @Drew You are correct. I missed the ending * in Python*. After typing Python*, the completion directly goes to *Python* and I can RET to enter it.